# Category names not used by python seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I am trying to do a `countplot` with meaningful category names. The dataset uses integers as codes for the categories and those integer values are displayed in the plot rather than the names I have assigned.

```
import pandas
# bug fix
pandas.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x:'%f'%x)
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot

s = pandas.Series([1,2,3,1,2,3,1])
print(s)
s = s.astype('category')
print(s)
s.cat.rename_categories(["A", "B", "C"])
print(s)

seaborn.countplot(x = s)
```

This code produces a plot with the original category values of 1, 2 and 3. I want A, B and C instead.

[image: plot produced]

The `print(s)` outputs are:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    1
dtype: int64
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    1
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 2, 3]
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    1
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 2, 3]
```

So it's changing the data type but not changing the values. However, when I do just the rename interactively, I get the following, though a `print(s)` will still return the number names.

```
In[108]: s.cat.rename_categories(["A", "B", "C"])
Out[108]: 
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    A
4    B
5    C
6    A
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [A, B, C]
```

How do I make the plot use the letters instead of the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.cat.rename_categories(["A", "B", "C"])` (like most pandas operations unless they accept an `inplace=True` option) generates a *new* object.  It doesn't change the `s` you already have, so you really haven't assigned any new names at all. You need to assign the result as well:

```
>>> s = s.cat.rename_categories(["A", "B", "C"])
>>> s
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    A
4    B
5    C
6    A
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [A, B, C]
>>> seaborn.countplot(x=s)
```

gives me

[image: example countplot]